type family instance for field types in servant's NamedRoutes
I'm looking for a way to decorate a servant API definition: Whenever an endpoint returns a list of things, I'd like to add a query parameter.
So far, I have a type family that works on APIs that are defined with the traditional approach using :<|>:
type family AddLimit a :: Type where
  AddLimit ((sym :: Symbol) :> rest) = sym :> AddLimit rest
  AddLimit (first :> rest) = first :> AddLimit rest
  AddLimit (left :<|> right) = AddLimit left :<|> AddLimit right
  AddLimit (Get contentTypes [res]) = QueryParam "limit" Int :> Get contentTypes [res]
  AddLimit (Get contentTypes res) = Get contentTypes res

(this would require more instances to be complete, but it's enough to show the idea)
That will work if my API looks like this:
type API =
  "foo" :> Get '[JSON] Int
    :<|> "bar" :> Get '[JSON] [Int]

But it won't work when using NamedRoutes:
data MyNamedAPI mode = MyNamedAPI
  { foo :: mode :- "foo" :> Get '[JSON] Int,
    bar :: mode :- "bar" :> Get '[JSON] [Int]
  }
  deriving stock (Generic)

I can add the following instance to the type family:
AddLimit (NamedRoutes nr) = AddLimit (ToServantApi nr)

but that will turn my API definition in the equivalent representation using :<|>.
Alternatively, I could wrap AddLimit around all fields manually:
data MyNamedAPI mode = MyNamedAPI
  { foo :: mode :- AddLimit ("foo" :> Get '[JSON] Int),
    bar :: mode :- AddLimit ("bar" :> Get '[JSON] [Int])
  }
  deriving stock (Generic)

Is there a way to use the type family to do that with less duplication? There is ToServant in servant-generic, but the inverse is only supported on the value level using fromServant

I wonder if you can use something like HKD (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higgledy-0.4.2.1/docs/Data-Generic-HKD-Types.html) here.

@Emily I was thinking something similar. maybe it's possible to use GenericMode: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.20.2/docs/Servant-API-Generic.html#t:GenericMode to introduce something like AddLimitT that does the type processing. I haven't found something that compiles yet, but that might be a way
